# Reactjs - accessing object values without repeating map looping

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

How can I access the object data and render it in React without having to repeatedly loop it through the map() function? I wanted something as simple as `this.state.profile.first_name` as the data is coming as a JSON object. I don't want to have to keep looping through the map every time I need to access data values.

```
getInitialState: function() {
        return ({
               profile: []
           });
        },
componentDidMount: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.get("/profile/"+ id, function(result){
            self.setState({
                profile: result
            })
        }) 
},

render: function(){         
    var header = React.createElement(
            'div', 
            {className: 'profile_header'},
            this.state.profile.map(item=>
                item.first_name +' '+ item.last_name
            ));

    var profile = React.createElement(
            'div', 
            {className: 'profile_main'}, 
            this.state.profile.map(item =>
                // would like to do something like 
                // <span>DOB:</span> item.dob <br />
                // <span>Gender:</span> item.gender <br />
            ));

    return React.createElement(
            'div',
             {className: 'profile-display'},
                 header,
                 profile
             );

}
```

Comment: Write a helper function that accepts a container and property name and `map`s inside?

Comment: Just for clarity, the data you are expecting is an array of array of objects? Or is it jut an object? A little confused because you said in the description that it's coming as an object, but in your code it is an array.

Comment: @djfdev, the data comes out as `[{"id": 1, "name": "Jen Madison".....}]`

Comment: Can you do `self.setState({ profile: result[0] })`? Doesn't look like you are expecting there to be more than one object in the array.